# Values of Column col1 that have multiple values in col2

Tags: sql

I have a table like this:

```
col1 col2
 a    10
 b    20
 a    30
 c    40
 a    05
```

I am trying to write a query to get all values in column col1 that have values 10,20,30 in column col2. I used AND statement but it returns nothing

Comment: Edit your question and show the query you used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use IN clause to give multiple inputs

```
   SELECT col1 FROM yourtable WHERE COL2 IN (10,20,30)
```

It is equivalent of doing:

```
   SELECT col1 FROM yourtable WHERE COL2 = 10 OR COL2 = 20 OR COL2 = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select col1
from t
where col2 in (10, 20, 30)
group by col1
having count(distinct col2) = 3;
```

The use of `AND` for this type of query is a very, very common mistake.  The problem is that no one row can have all three values -- and `WHERE` is only looking at one row at a time when it is filtering.  Instead, you need to get all the rows with these values and then bring those rows together to see how many matches there are for each `col1` value.